# Multiple timezones time output in Atlassian Confluence

Tags: confluence

I need to output time in different timezones on the Confluence page. Does anyone know if there already is such macro or some workaround to achieve this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to do the same thing.  I found I can get the local one with a macro that has this line:

```
$action.dateFormatter.formatGivenString("HH:mm", $content.currentDate)
```

I would ask this under https://answers.atlassian.com.

Comment: I think there already is [a similar question](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/313150/date-and-time-macro). But, it still does not tell how to set specific TimeZone or specific Date.

Comment: I couldn't find one so I created this one: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/10402170/multiple-timezones-displayed-in-confluence